# logical replication. How do I change the subscriber to new master?

Tags: linux, postgresql, postgresql-11

I'm migrating Linux distros and need to migrate the Postgres 11 to new master. I can do a streaming replication and have little to no downtime or do a dump. That I got down.

My problem is how do I switch the subscribed slave server to the new master Postgres server without any data loss or issues. I'm not sure if I unsubscribe slave and subscribe it to new master will it replicate new tables or will it start from where it left off.

Anyone have any tips or links? I haven't found anything on google.

Answer (score 1):

If you create the subscription to the new master `with (copy_data = false)` it will not try to copy the data again.

As long as you let all changes replay before dropping the old subscription, and create the new subscription before anyone else is allowed to start making new changes, then there should be no loss of data.

That is a bit fraught though.  It would certainly be easier and less error prone but slower just to recreate the replica from scratch and copy over the data again.

Comment: Thank you for the info. Would I need to unsubscribe the server to the old master then subscribe it to the new master?

Comment: If the old master will be destroyed and never used again, I guess you don't **need** to drop the subscription to it.  But it would be tidier to do so.  If you can no longer contact the old master, then dropping the subscription takes extra steps--you need to set it to disabled, then disassociate it from the slot name, then drop it.